# Check whether a string contains given characters

Tags: java, string

I am trying to check whether a code block has completed using a while loop.  It will have reached this state when there are no longer any instances of '+', '-', '*', '/', '(' or ')' in the string. The code I posted was my attempt at it, although it's not working.

```
while (string.contains("+-*/()") == false)
{
modifier code
}
```

Comment: And what's your exact problem? Could you show the code in the *modified code* section as well?

Comment: `contains()` will search for instances of that phrase, not instances of all those characters anywhere. So unless your string literally contains `+-*/()`, it will always return false.

Comment: If you're not doing any processing, why not just use `String#replaceAll(String, String)`?

Answer (score 1):

For a solution with slightly less backtracking and escaping:

```
String quoted = Pattern.quote("+-*/()");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[" + quoted + "]");
while (pattern.matcher(string).find()) {
    // modifier code
}
```

Even better would be avoiding making the `Matcher` in a loop, and using [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher.appendTail()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) in the *modifier code* to create the result in a `StringBuffer` in one pass. But that depends on what the modifier code does. (And I'd still have to brush up on how you use those methods.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) and a regular expression like:

```
while (!string.matches(".*[-+/()*]+.*"))
{
// modifier code
}
```

Edited to correct Regex now

Comment: this regex is wrong; you forgot to escape the `-` in the character class.

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I've corrected the order now, so no need to escape it